# Generic Insert Trigger

Tags: sql-server, database

I have the following scenario: Two SQL Server 2008 databases (let's say DB-A and DB-B). In both i have a lot o tables. For only some tables on DB-A I need to copy some of the records inserted(Based on a condition) into the same table on DB-B. Of course both tables needs to have same structure. My initial approach is to create triggers for Insert on the tables FROM DB-A to copy the recors to DB-B based on the condition. Now I have two problems:

**1) Is there a way to write those triggers on a generic way (Without explict fields names)?**

This is because in the future its very possible that i need to add fields to the tables and i woulnd't like to have to modify the triggers every time.

**2) How can i ensure that the DB-B is updated when the record from DB-A is edited?**

The records from the DB-A could be edited after insert, so DB-B won't know about this edition. I could create a trigger for update also. The problem is with primary keys, that will be different in both tables.

Any ideas? thanks!

Comment: This is a solved problem. Lots of smart people have written replication tools already, you should give those a try before rolling your own solution. To start with you should look at the tools built into Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: Are you talking about Transactional replication? The problem is that i only need SOME records from DB-A table be copied to DB-B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This scenario doesn't look like a good one for triggers. If by some reason insertion in DB-B fails, INSERT in DB-A will be rolled back too. You can not write triggers in a 'generic' way. Triggers badly affects INSERT performance. If by some reason you have no trigger in place for some time, you have no warranty than databases are in sync.

So, if two databases should be in sync almost in real-time, I'd suggest transactional replication. Replication brings all changes in published tables from one DB to another and keep data in sync. Tables in source and target databases have the same structures. So if tables in DB-B are different, it wouldn't work.

If real-time is not required, you can create stored procedure to move required data between databases and call this SP by schedule. SP will check and move all insert\deletes\updates from one DB to another table-by-table. In this case table structures can differ between databases.

Comment: Thank you for you time and comment. The problem with transactional replication is that I only need to move SOME of the records from DB-A table to DB-B (Based on a WHERE condition), not all the table. The SP approach could work, but every time it runs I need to check all the records to see if there is some missing in DB-B. If my table have many records could by a performance problem, don't you think?

Comment: You can define filter on a table in replication, it is not a problem. Indeed, this SP could take a lot of resources, depending on table and logic. Usually it is not that bad, and we can help this process a lot. We can store 'watermark' for a table, to check only last part of data, we can store row version in a row to detect updates, etc.

Comment: I didn't know i can make conditional replication on a table. That could be a very good solution. But how can I handdle Primary key in those cases? The same record from DB-A could have a Diferent ID on DB-B or am I wrong?

Comment: If table in DB-B is in replication, it is, hm, replica of DB-A's table. As part of replication setup table from DB-A will be moved to DB-B. So there will be no differences in PK.